# Different WebSocket "onmessage" handlers depending on screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

My React Native app (iOS and Android) uses a single global WebSocket connection.

I want to respond to the same messages from the server differently depending on the screen, e.g. one way on the home screen (A) and differently on screen B.

Because the home screen is still mounted and "active" after screen B has been opened, presumably I can't just overwrite the websocket "onmessage" handler as that would lead to inconsistencies.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing some code on what you're trying to achieve, I think what you want in general is a subscription model. You have only one handler registered with the socket, but that handler can delegate to other functions that can be added/removed as desired.

In general, I would recommend creating the websocket connection somewhere in the react tree such as a hook with a context provider. To avoid cluttering up the idea here, though, let's assume your websocket connection is defined a static context (i.e. in a module, rather than a component or hook).

```
// socket.js
const messageHandlers = new Set()

export const addMessageHandler = (handler) => {
  messageHandlers.add(handler)
}

export const removeMessageHandler = (handler) => {
  messageHandlers.delete(handler)
}

const socket = new WebSocket('ws://example.com')

socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  messageHandlers.forEach((handler) => handler(event))
}
```

Then in your screen:

```
import { addMessageHandler, removeMessageHandler } from '/path/to/socket.js'

const SomeScreen = () => {
  useCallback(() => {
    const handler = (event) => { /* do something with event */ }
      
    addMessageHandler(handler)
    return () => removeMessageHandler(handler)
  }, [])
}
```

This will keep the listener alive even if the screen is in the background. If you're using react-navigation, you can also make it register only while the screen is the current screen using [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) such as:

```
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const handler = (event) => { /* do something with event */ }
      
      addMessageHandler(handler)
      return () => removeMessageHandler(handler)
    }, [])
  )
```

Comment: I know you're supposed to avoid comments that don't add anything further, but this solution worked absolutely flawlessly for my use case - very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, bit late but wouldn’t this create a new connection everytime this file is imported in the components? And if so why not just create hook that takes handler as an argument without this whole looping process

Comment: ES modules are never loaded more than once. Every importing file gets the same copy (which for frontend apps, is often packed into larger files anyway). This is one global connection with arbitrary numbers of handlers registered in different places throughout the tree. You could expose it via a `ReactContext`, but "takes handler as an argument" would need to be very careful to use `useCallback`, lest you keep adding more and more handlers on every render.

Comment: Are you saying that `new Websocket` part of code won't be run multiple times if i import socket.js into two different non relating files (no parent-children relation)?

Comment: Correct. Both with node `require` and ES modules, a file is loaded the *first* time something imports it, then all subsequent imports get the same values. They're all "global" values. Note that this has some implications, particularly for unit testing, since the same value will be reused across all of the tests. Thus, it's generally better to create it in a hook that provides the value via `ReactContext`. That way, all of your tests can get a "clean" instance, and you can use React's `useEffect` to connect, disconnect, etc.

Comment: @EricHaynes, can you please explain, why have you specifically suggested `useCallback`. What if we use `useEffect` without any dependency? Would it be any problem?

Comment: It's been a while. I assume I was covering a case where the new reference to `useFocusEffect` caused it to rerun for each render. Try some `console.log` in there and see.